# How to iterate through custom config section entries?

Tags: asp.net, .net

My custom config section looks like this:

```
  <MySection>
    <add name="a" value="111"/>
    <add name="b" value="222"/>
    <add name="c" value="333"/>
    ...
  </MySection>
```

I know [how to write a custom config section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but how to iterate through all its entries?

Problem solved with : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You mean parse the section????

Comment: I mean just get the entries from <MySection>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse your section use:

```
var config = (SampleConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sampleConfiguration");

config.YourCustomProperty = "Hello World";
```

If you want to iterate through the XML elements manually (which would be a really strange requirement), you could use LINQ to XML

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

....

var xml = XDocument.Load("path to your config file");

var section = from e in xml.Root.Elements("your section name").Elements()
              select e;
```

If you need dynamic items, then perhaps you could use the **[ConfigurationElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx)** and then parse your section and work with your collection objects instead of working with the XML directly

Comment: Thanks. This link answers my question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use 'GetSection' (link below).

```
// Get the AppSettings section.
var sect = (MySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("mysection");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.getsection.aspx